# What is wrong with my method for raising a complex number to a power

Tags: java, complex-numbers

My method uses De Moivre's Theorem to raise a complex number a+bi to a power. However, I am not getting the right answers.

I double-checked all my math and it seems to be okay, so I'm thinking that I may have done my code wrong.

```
public class ComplexNumber {
//instance variables
    private int real;
    private int imaginary;

//constructors
    public ComplexNumber(int a, int b) {
        real = a;
        imaginary = b;  

//methods
    public ComplexNumber pow(int x) {
        int z = (int) Math.pow(this.getModulus(),x);
        int T = (int) Math.atan(this.imaginary/this.real);
        int a = (int) (z * Math.cos(x*T));
        int b = (int) (z * Math.sin(x*T));
        return new ComplexNumber(a, b);
    }

    public double getModulus() {
        int z = (int) Math.sqrt(real*real + imaginary*imaginary);
        return z;
    }
```

For instance, for the complex number 3+4i raised to the 1st power, I am getting 5+0i.

Comment: Might have something to do with with how you are casting everything to `int` and losing information in the process?  It would be helpful if you show how you call this information and what the variables like `this.imaginary` contain/are defined.

Comment: The code you posted is not a [mcve]. Please read that link to learn how to write one. And if you haven't already done so, please also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Also, using `atan` instead of `atan2` means you lose the quadrant